# Capture twitter #hashtags with regex, but exclude the #

Tags: javascript, regex, hashtag

I'd like to capture only the content of a twitter `#hashtag`, not including the `#`. So `#hashtag` becomes `hashtag`. My current solution involves stripping the `#` with javascript, which seems clunky. Is there a way to capture a full word *after but not including* a character using just regex? I'm looking for a 'yes' or 'no' here.

I have this string:

```
"This is an #awesome tweet with #amazing #hashtags all over the #place"
```

When I use this regex:

```
#(\w+)
```

I get this:

```
["#awesome", "#amazing", "#hashtags", "#place"]
```

but I want to get this:

```
["awesome", "amazing", "hashtags", "place"]
```

Is this possible to do in just regex or will I need to continue to strip the `#` via the rest of my javascript code?

Comment: What's your js code?

Comment: The regex is fine. Just use it in the right code to only grab Group 1 contents.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, this is not a duplicate to the one you've suggested. My question is a yes/no on whether this can be done with just regex.

Comment: No, you must match `#(\w+)` and grab Group 1. Or match `#\w+` and remove the first char of each match